# android display emoticons in edittext and allow the user to delete them

Tags: android, android-edittext, emoticons

My problem goes like this, I manage to displaying emoticons correctly in `EditText`, but if the user try to delete this emoticons in some devices the deleting instead to delete the emoticons after one time press on the keyboard delete icon it's need to be pressed two or three time according the emoticons string

below is my code:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(emoticon.getResourceId());    
int startCursor = mTextInput.getSelectionStart();
int endCursor = mTextInput.getSelectionEnd();
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append(emoticon.getStr());
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(d), builder.length() - emoticon.getStr().length(), builder.length(),
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mTextInput.getText().replace(startCursor, endCursor, builder);
```